# How to destroy a frame by clicking on a button?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to destroy the frame by clicking on a button. I searched everywhere and it seems that I'm doing this right. but it is not working.

```
public class LoginWindow {

    public void CreateLoginWindow () {

        /** Set Style to Main Frame **/
        JFrame main_window = new JFrame();
        main_window.setUndecorated(true);
        main_window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        main_window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        main_window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        main_window.setVisible(false);
        main_window.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/MainWindow-bg.jpg")));
        main_window.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        main_window.setSize(1920,1080);
        main_window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        /** Some Codes **/

        JButton login_button = new JButton("Click to Exit");
        login_button.setBounds(920,480,120,45);

        /** Login Button Action **/
        login_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ValidateLogin validateLogin = new ValidateLogin();
            Boolean valid = validateLogin.ValidateLoginAction(username_field.getText(),password_field.getText());
            main_window.dispose();
            }
        });

        main_window.add(login_button);
        main_window.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

It seems `ValidateLogin validateLogin = new ValidateLogin(); Boolean valid = validateLogin.ValidateLoginAction(username_field.getText(),password_field.getText());` make some problems.

And this is my `ValidateLogin` Class :

```
public class ValidateLogin {

    public Boolean ValidateLoginAction (String username, String password){

        ConnectToDB validate_login = new ConnectToDB();
        String right_password = validate_login.GetPassOfAnUsername(username);
        if ( right_password.equals(password) ){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

And this is my `ConnectToDB` Class :

```
public class ConnectToDB {

    /** Connect to Database **/
    private Connection connect() {

        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:E://Resturant Project/db/Resturant.db";
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }

    /** Get Password of an Username **/
    public String GetPassOfAnUsername(String username){

        String password = "SELECT Password FROM Person WHERE UserName = '" + username +"'";

        try (Connection connection = this.connect();
             PreparedStatement statement= connection.prepareStatement(password);
             ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery()) {

            return results.getString("Password");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

And this is my `MainWindow` Class :

```
public class MainWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoginWindow loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
        loginWindow.CreateLoginWindow();
    }

}
```

Comment: This code is working for me, can you explain what exactly does not work for you?

Comment: @DasElias Do you get close after clicking on button? I don't!

Comment: Yes, the window is closed, but the JVM does not exit.

Comment: @ElyasBehroozizade Please edit your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @Progman It should be fine now

Comment: @ElyasBehroozizade The source code is not complete, the `main()` method is missing. Also, it is not minimal, because the SQL stuff is not relevant for this problem. I tried it with your code anyway and it closes the window and stops the JVM, as expected. If you have a problem with the code **you** actual have, you must provide it as a [mcve], which clearly show that the window is not closing and/or that the JVM is not stopping, depending on the problem you have.

Comment: @Progman the problem is when I delete `Boolean valid = validateLogin.ValidateLoginAction(username_field.getText(),password_field.getText());` everything works fine. (code edited)

Comment: @ElyasBehroozizade You might get a NullPointerException inside your `addActionListener()` handler, before you get to the `main_window.dispose();` line. Check the exceptions you get from your `ValidateLogin` and `ConnectToDB` class, check your return values from the methods you call and check for exceptions in your event handler. You might want to add additional `System.out.println();` statements to see where your thread is going (or not going).

Answer (score 0):

Have the **username_field** and **password_field** variables been instantiated somewhere? Perhaps the line where you are accessing the getText() method is throwing a NullPointerException when the **actionPerformed** method is being called and so the program never reaches the main_window.dispose() line. 
Try checking if both of those variables are null when the actionPerformed method is being executed before you try to access the getText() method from them.

On a further note, check if the connection the database is being established successfully.

```
ConnectToDB validate_login = new ConnectToDB();
String right_password = validate_login.GetPassOfAnUsername(username);
```

The second line might also throw a NullPointerException in case **validate_login** is null because your code will return null from your ConnectToDB() constructor in case the connection fails.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and I am able to close the window and jvm exits also. I provide below the button action code snippet.

```
login_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    ValidateLogin validateLogin = new ValidateLogin();
                    Boolean valid = validateLogin.ValidateLoginAction(username_field.getText(),password_field.getText());
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {
                    //handle exception
                }
                finally {
                    main_window.dispose();
                }
            }
        });
```